# JPA/Hibernate preUpdate doesn't update parent object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In my application I defined following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "forums")
public class Forum {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private Date lastActivity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "forum", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<Post> posts;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private String username;
    private String content;
    private Date creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Forum forum;

    public Post() {
        creationDate = new Date();
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void onPersist() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": onPersist");
        if (creationDate == null) {
            creationDate = new Date();
        }

        forum.setLastActivity(creationDate);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void onUpdate() {
        forum.setLastActivity(new Date());
    }
```

If I try adding new posts to forum entity, `lastActivity` field is correctly updated in database by `@PrePersist` callback. 
But if I try to update post entity using following code:

```
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  Post post = entityManager.find(Post.class, "postId");
  post.setContent("New post text");
  entityManager.merge(post);
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

only post data are updated and `lastActivity` field value doesn't change. In my opinion `@PreUpdate` method should do the trick and update Forum entity.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not bug, even that with a fast try this worked for me way you expected. Negative news is that it is not guaranteed to work, because of:

From page 93 in JPA 2.0 specification:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>   invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity
>   instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>   context.[43] A lifecycle callback method may modify the
>   non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

And page 95:

> It is implementation-dependent as to whether callback methods are
>   invoked before or after the cascading of the lifecycle events to
>   related entities. Applications should not depend on this ordering.

Comment: This isn’t a very good news for me but I really appreciate your help.  Do you know any work around for  this problem or maybe you can tell me what implementation did you used to test my code? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Hibernate 3.6.2, HSQL. Not in server but as Java SE, resource local transactions.

Comment: I strongly recommend on not relying on this, as @MikkoMaunu suggests. `@PreUpdate` did not work for me when updating a field in a one-to-many child entity using Hibernate 4.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

`post.merge()` has no use here. `post` is clearly attached to the session already.

Make sure you've got the `content` attribute mapped to a column, if it is not, Hibernate has no way of telling if the entity is dirty, and therefore flush the changes to the DB.

Comment: Indeed <code>post.merge()</code> is unnecessary in this case. Execution of mentioned code changes DB value of post.content field. My problem is that post.forum.lastActivity field isn't updated.